# According to Prisma, the referenced column does not exist in the database, but the client is created without any problems

Tags: mysql, prisma

I have created this model in my prism scheme:

```js
model Organization {

  ID          Int     @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  Name        String  @db.VarChar(50)
  UniqueName  String  @unique @db.VarChar(12)
  LoginScheme String  @unique @db.VarChar(100)
  Owner       HubUser @relation(fields: [OwnerID], references: [ID])
  OwnerID     Int

  @@map("organizations")
}
```

The client can be generated without any problems using `npx prisma generate`
The table in my database looks like this:
[image: Database Table]

But now I get the following error message when I want to query the table:

```
Invalid `client.organization.findUniqueOrThrow()` invocation in
C:\Users\<USER>\WebstormProjects\API\dist\Controllers\OrganizationController.js:81:63

   78 try {
   79     try {
   80         const client = await DatabaseController_1.DatabaseController.CreateClient("organizationhub");
→  81         const matchingOrg = await client.organization.findUniqueOrThrow(
  The column `organizationhub.organizations.OwnerID` does not exist in the current database.
```

I see that this error says that the OwnerID column does not exist in the table, which is true, this column only exists in the schema because the field is referenced.
But in the database, the column "Owner" already has an FK relationship. Do I really have to create a new column in the database just so that Prisma can deal with it?

Or is something wrong here in my scheme?

Comment: Can you please share the query you are performing?

Comment: Hi, of course!
The query:

 
`const matchingOrg = await client.organization.findUniqueOrThrow(
                    {where: {LoginScheme: scheme.toLowerCase()}});`

Comment: Please share the full schema file as well. This will help in figuring this out.

Comment: Coming right up:
https://gist.github.com/manuelpoelzl/40bdcbe152e4e06cd985e401eba37053

Comment: Hey @RaphaelEtim,
I was able to fix the problem, it was actually a simple thing I missed, I had to add @map("Owner") to the organization model OwnerID field, the field just wasn't mapped to the correct database field.